$x_{1} = \sqrt{2}$ and $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+x_{n}}$. Show that the sequence converges and find it's limit.
The question
$x_{1} = \sqrt{2}$ and $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+x_{n}}$. Show that the sequence converges and find it's limit.
Attempt
If I assume that the limit exists, then I am able to find the limit. But how to show the existence in the first place. I tried to go along the direction to show that it is monotonic and bounded, but no manipulation could give any tangible path. Kindly help.

Use induction to prove that $0<x_n<2,n\in\mathbb{N}$ and then prove that $(x_n)$ is monotonic.

Oh! I can see the $0 < x_{n} < 2$ part, how to start the monotonicity part? any hints for that @E.Papapetros

$$x_{n}-x_{n+1}=x_n-\sqrt{2+x_n}=\frac{x_n^2-x_n-2}{x_n+\sqrt{2+x_n}}=\frac{(x_n+1)(x_n-2)}{x_n+\sqrt{2+x_n}}.$$

Thanks a lot. That's quite elegant!
